# Android screen coordinates transformation

Tags: java, android, math

Android screen coordinates are as below:
[image]

I want to bring (0,0) at the center of screen from top left corner.
Can anyone support regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can operate the canvas of view.
Translating the canvas to center point ->Then draw the image on canvas.